# spss to xml conversion

Tags: xml, spss

I have done missing value analysis using SPSS 20, I want to convert the missing value analysis into XML so that I can import that XML into PASW modeler. How can I do it ?
Note that PASW Statistics is not working in my version

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a PMML file?  MVA does not support that.  If you just want the output tables as XML, you can do that with OMS, but  it's not obvious how Modeler would use them.

Answer (score 0):

You could always copy your resulting output to excel (tested with 2007), apply XML mappings and then save to XML DATA format, long-winded but it works.